# A word for shouting athlete's name as an applause

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a question about a single word. What is it called when spectators or the audience shout an athlete's name as a support repeatedly?

Comment: This would have sent mixed messages from the supporters of Albert Richmond "Boo" Morcom, who was an American track and field athlete in the 30s and 40s. But there's probably not a word describing the practice, Amir.

Comment: Perhaps a "cheer", or "chant".

Answer (score 1):

*Cheering* refers to doing anything to support the athletes, which could be shouting, but also dancing, clapping and playing music.

*Chanting* refers to repeatedly say something.

So both of these can apply in this situation.